# Aurora vs Redshift vs DynamoDB for Indie Game Backend?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-redshift, amazon-aurora

I've been reading a whole bunch on these databases but still am just not sure what to use.

I need a backend for a game I am developing. This backend needs to store user accounts, the items the user has and the score of the user.

At the start of the game the user will query the database for their items. When they get a new item it will add it to their account on the database. Items will be stored as a large JSON blob.

So this database will not be accessed frequently. It does not need to store a huge amount of data, as it really only needs 1 entry per user. But it should be able to scale into the millions.

I will need to query the database to determine what users belong to which particular categories, or teams.

As cheap as I can get on storing this data in a reliable and adequately fast way is ideal.

What is the best option for this?

Answer (score 8):

**Redshift** is a data warehouse and generally used for OLAP(analytical) processes. Analytical DBs are too slow for transactional processes and do not generally obey primary key foreign key constraints. While **Aurora** and **DynamoDB** are OLTP(transactional) database. In your case if you are to keep all the data in a single JSON entry it would be better to use DynamoDB but I would suggest to use Aurora as it is a RDBMS having fix schema, but you will have to keep multiple entries per user in another table although retrieving them will be just a single join query.

Answer (score 3):

Redshift will not meet your needs. It's an OLAP database designed to scan huge amounts of data in parallel. As a very basic example, you might export your live database to Redshift and query it to see if any players have an extreme amount of money or lots of duplicate items, and look for cheaters that way. It's terrible at querying and updating single records.

Aurora and DynamoDB are both OLTP databases that are designed to handle tasks just like you have in mind. From personal experience I can say that Aurora would have no trouble scaling up: I work with a mid-range Aurora instance that consistently provides ~2500 QPS over multiple billion-record tables. If anything, DynamoDB is more scalable than Aurora at a similar price point, so I wouldn't worry about scaling. :)

For the simple schema you describe, there isn't a hugely compelling reason to choose one of Aurora or DynamoDB over the other. AWS has [serverless Aurora](https://aws.amazon.com/rds/aurora/serverless/) in preview, which would be the lowest-cost choice for light usage if it were available right now. Perhaps use a t2.small with Aurora for now and migrate to serverless when you can? DynamoDB is also quite cheap at the low end, though.